# How to access latest props when using the useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React documentation states the following:

> [Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

And therefore they recommend using the callback form of `setState` where you can access the most up-to-date prop.

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

However, how can the same be done using hooks? namely, `useState`. How can I access the most up-to-date prop using `useState`?

Comment: In functional components props are always up to date

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Can you please point me to a source/documentation, or anything that I could read more on? I am also curious to know why is it that this is the case. I would most sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: I don't have the source, but in functional components the entire body of the component is run with the new props which isn't the case in class components where only the `render` method is called.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No, check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tmuw3z?file=src%2FApp.js. Click the div, see it outputs 1. If you implement similar example with classes and `setState` which OP refers to, it will output 4.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava in your example props have exactly the same value as in parent. It's state that didn't change.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ok what about this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-2cfakq?file=index.js ?

Comment: You are right. The bahaviour indeed differs. It's probably impossible without `useEffect`.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Honestly I don't even see how you can do that with `useEffect`. It's strange I can't find any info about this change in the docs.

Comment: Listen for prop change in `useEffect` and run the state update you need when prop changes. `useState` doesn't know that the props exist so it's impossible to do the same thing as in class components.